# Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org; Name or service not known

Tags: linux, vim, fedora

I'm trying to install vim in fedora 19, I gets this error, anyone have idea please?

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]#  yum -y install vim-enhanced 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-19&arch=x86_64 error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org; Name or service not known"
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: dl.google.com; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from google-chrome: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: dl.google.com; Name or service not known"
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]#
```

Answer (score 4):

The first two things to do are:

1) Make sure your Fedora host's internet connection is up, and

2) verify that you can `ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org`.

If you can "ping" it (and you *SHOULD* be able to), then "yum" should succeed.

If, for whatever reason, you still can't connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org, then perhaps you can use an alternate mirror instead:

- http://fedorasolved.org/post-install-solutions/yum-local-mirror-list
- http://planetmirror.com/pub/fedoralegacy/
- http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/download.fedoralegacy.org/

Comment: ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org works. I can access internet using my web browser in fedora. this is the result of ping `PING wildcard.fedoraproject.org (213.175.193.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mirrors.fedoraproject.org (213.175.193.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=342 ms
64 bytes from mirrors.fedoraproject.org (213.175.193.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=345 ms
`

Comment: The error is clearly saying "your DNS can't resolve host mirrors.fedoraproject.org".  Your "ping" says that you can.  Perhaps it was a momentary network glitch?  SUGGESTION: 1) run `sudo yum clean all`, 2) re-verify `ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org`, 3) double-check with `yum list`, and finally 4) re-try `yum install vim-enhanced`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but Firefox was amongst the casualties, and won't run.
Eventually, I figured out I needed to add an IP entry for the host site in /etc/hosts
Several runs of yum-complete-transaction later, the software updater is still failing though. I think a reinstall might be quicker.